# Warning shown when adding child UIViewController from code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added a child `UIViewController's` view to a `UIViewController` on the storyboard from code instead of using segue. The custom `UIViewController` contains `UISearchController`. Following is the code I am using for adding the custom/child `UIViewController`:

```
self.customController = [[CustomUIViewController alloc] init];
[self.searchBarContainerView addSubview:self.customController.view];
```

'`self.searchBarContainerView`' in the above code is an `UIView` for displaying search bar of `UISearchController`. This code is working fine and the search bar is shown without issues at runtime. However when I am clicking inside search bar, following warning message is logged in the output window

> "presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is
>   discouraged "

I need help is fixing this warning from being shown.

Comment: you are trying to present uisearchcontroller on CustomUIViewcontroller, which is not the root controller. Hence the warning message occurs.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri When adding UISearchController to root controller directly I am facing issue with search bar stretching out of table view's header view on clicking in search bar. That's the reason I have added UISearchController in a custom UIViewController. So that search bar is not exceeding width of UIViewController. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704967/how-to-resizing-issue-of-uisearchcontroller-searchbar-when-focused) which I posted earlier

Comment: I'd suggest using UISearchbar instead of using UISearchController to avoid these issues.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I know UISearchbar would be better, but I am trying to use latest standard UISearchController. There are issues with UISearchController which may be fixed in future Xcode versions, meanwhile I am looking for any workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cy-4AH suggested and as per the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895491/how-to-use-addchildviewcontroller-in-subview) I have added following steps and it worked.

```
[self addChildViewController:self.customController];
self.customController = [[CustomUIViewController alloc] init];
[self.searchBarContainerView addSubview:self.customController.view];
[self.customController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```